# Installation of timescaledb failing

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, postgresql-12, timescaledb, i386

I've attempted to install timescaledb on Ubuntu 18.04 (32bit) with Postgresql 12 using:
https://docs.timescale.com/latest/getting-started/installation/ubuntu/installation-apt-ubuntu

When I run sudo apt install timescaledb-2-postgresql-12 I get the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package timescaledb-2-postgresql-12
```

I then tried to go through and build the code locally (from the repository https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb) which was successful (on the make) but I was not able to see the "next steps" for what to do after the build. When I attempt to add the extension in the postgres.conf file by adding "shared_preload_libraries = 'timescaledb' " then restarting. On the restart I get the error

```
2021-02-22 07:24:28.711 EST [18311] syorke@postgres ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/timescaledb.control": No such file or directory
```

In the timescaledb.control is:

```
# timescaledb extension
comment = 'Enables scalable inserts and complex queries for time-series data'
default_version = '2.0.1'
module_pathname = '$libdir/timescaledb-2.0.1'
#extension cannot be relocatable once installed because it uses multiple schemas and that is forbidden by PG.
#(though this extension is relocatable during installation).
relocatable = false
```

My question is am I going about this correctly where the package was not found?
Should I replace the /usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/timescaledb.control with the timescaledb.control.in in the directory where I did my build for timescaledb?

In that control file from the build is:

```
# timescaledb extension
comment = 'Enables scalable inserts and complex queries for time-series data'
default_version = '@PROJECT_VERSION_MOD@'
module_pathname = '$libdir/timescaledb-@PROJECT_VERSION_MOD@'
#extension cannot be relocatable once installed because it uses multiple schemas and that is forbidden by PG.
#(though this extension is relocatable during installation).
relocatable = false
```

What would '@PROJECT_VERSION_MOD@' be replaced with and where is the $libdir set?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I experienced the same problem. This was casued by having multiple installations of PostgreSQL on the same server. PostgreSQL was already installed when I ran the TimescaleDB-bundle containing PostgreSQL 14. Solved the problem by uninstalling both 12 and 14 and then by re-installing the TimescaleDB bundle...

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just successuffly install on Ubuntu 20.04 using the script locate here

https://packagecloud.io/timescale/timescaledb/install

instead of doing the step 3 on the normal installation process
https://docs.timescale.com/install/latest/self-hosted/installation-debian/#installing-self-hosted-timescaledb-on-debian-based-systems

Then follow step 4 & 5 as on the documentation

As you have install from source maybe you will need to uninstall first